Why is Bc8 "interesting"? What's the plan for Black if this move was played?
[Fen ""]
[Startply "49"]
[StartFlipped "1"]
[Title "Rasulov - Naroditsky, Titled Tuesday 2022-08-16"]

1.Nf3 Nf6 2.g3 g6 3.Bg2 Bg7 4.O-O O-O 5.d4 d6 6.c4 Nbd7 7.b3 e5
8.dxe5 dxe5 9.Nc3 e4 10.Nd4 Re8 11.Qc2 c6 12.Rd1 Qe7 13.a4 a5
14.Bf4 Nc5 15.h3 Nh5 16.Be3 f5 17.Rab1 Rf8 18.Qd2 Ne6 19.Nxe6
Bxe6 20.Bg5 Qc5 21.Rbc1 Rae8 22.Qd6 Qxd6 23.Rxd6 Be5 24.Rdd1
Kg7 25.e3 *

Why is Bc8 in this position "interesting" as per GM Naroditsky (1:00:19 in this video)?
Full game, Lichess, Chess.com
One comment in Reddit is this,

"You first need to understand the move, this is not a waiting move
(and, btw, waiting moves are very rare and very specific to some
positions, like endgames where time is precious and very dominant
positions where you can lose a move and still be almost winning). It
is a move that greatly improves the position, as now the bishop is not
exposed and liberates the rook. So we improve other pieces without
making the bishop worse, as it wasn't doing anything on e6 anyway.
For example, if black plays 1...h6 2.Bf4 Nxf4 3.gxf4 Bf6 White does
4.Rd6 and we can't expel the rook right now with Be7 or Rd8 as we hang the Be6. We need to first defend the bishop to do that. So it's way
better if we do that first avoid problems later on.
In general grounds, Bc8 is a good move that can be made in a second as
it is a very common pattern. But in general you want to calculate and
be aware of your opponent's ideas, that's how you usually find this
kind of moves."

What are the other plans?

Why is the reddit comment you quote not enough an explanation ?

the second paragraph of the comment specifically. also it still protects the 7th rank infiltrations
